# How to adjust Linksys LGS310MPC CLI terminal length?

Tags: command-line, switch

I've SSH'd into the Linksys CLI with PowerShell, and when I do a `show current running-config` the config is so long that it feels like I'm holding down <kbd>Enter</kbd> for an eternity.

PowerShell's output history is much longer than PuTTy I've noticed so I'm hoping someone knows the Linksys command to set `terminal length 0` like you would for a Cisco. Terminal length 0 did not work by the way.

None of the commands in the help menu seemed to indicate there was a command for setting the terminal length so if you just can't, let me know.

Otherwise, if there is another way to export the config file to the device I'm sessioned in with that would work just as well and be just as great.

Comment: Can’t you just run this SSH command from PowerShell: `ssh username@123.456.789.0 show current running-config`? Basically the SSH command with the commands you want to run on the remote following it?

Comment: Also, please do not cross post questions like this across SE sites [like what you posted to Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/1094705/100013).

Comment: Yes, so that is exactly what I'm doing, however, the configuration file does not output all at once. It outputs 21 lines and then I have --More-- on the bottom of the screen from which point on, you have to press enter for a new line one line at a time or else hold enter for maybe a whole minute. I didn't time it but it feels like an eternity. Besides, holding enter for too long will eventually result in the computer holding the key presses in memory until its executed all of them. Not great when you visually recognize you're at the EOF but the session wants to execute 100 more enter keys.